# 'E:Malformed line 60 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse)'

Tags: apt, updates, update-manager

I've gone through all of the other reports of this but when ever i follow the instructions and it opens my sources.list there are no numbers lines and there is barely anything in it.

i saved my sources.list to pastebin, here is the link http://pastebin.com/tQqpBtVd

Screenshots of my software sources:

[image: ubuntu software]
Please help my figure out what the problem is.

[image: other software]

Comment: Can you recreate your sources.list file by typing "sources" on the dash and then opening the "Software sources" software and ticking only the first four options in the "ubuntu software" tab and then try again?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the "ubuntu software" and "other software" tab of "software sources" software or a link to the screenshots?

Comment: Yes, here are the links 
http://i60.tinypic.com/i2khnk_th.png
And
http://oi59.tinypic.com/2ezjm1w.jpg

Comment: http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/ use this to generate a new sources.list file

Comment: Can you disable all ppa's by unchecking the ticks besides the ppa's in "other software" and then try again?

Comment: no its is saying sources in line 50 can not be read
screen shot: http://oi60.tinypic.com/2h58h8g.jpg

Comment: yesterday it was working fine until i enabled sources partner to install Adobe Reader. Could that be the problem?